# What is the rate for Federal Excise Tax on DSL/Cable Internet Connections

Tags: taxes, irs

I noticed the federal excise tax on my Internet bill (DSL) go from 2.5% of the subtotal to 2.6% of the subtotal.

How are these taxes figured out? I saw in an IRS publication that telephone communications is 3% - but cannot find good information on the subject.

Comment: It might help to know what state you live in and what ISP you use.

Comment: WI Century Link. I didnt think that mattered due to it being federal.